# How to print a report with one button in Odoo9?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I have a button that will print a report ( view Qweb ) but when i press the button to print on the form I get the following message:

TypeError: print_report() takes at least 6 arguments (5 given)

The button that I have in view is as follows:

And the function that is used to print is:

```
@api.v7

def print_report(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

    if context is None:

        context = {}

    data = {}

    data['ids'] = context.get('active_ids', [])

    data['model'] = context.get('active_model', 'ir.ui.menu')



    return self.pool['report'].get_action(cr, uid, [], 'custom_module.report_pricelist', data=data, context=context)
```

PLease help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hello don't use decorate, If you using new api then do this:

```
def print_report(self, data):    
    return self.env['report'].get_action(self, 'custom_module.report_pricelis', data=data)
```

I hope so will helpful for you.